# Replace green pixels with gray using imagemagick `convert` command

Tags: command-line, bash, imagemagick

I want to replace green pixels in [this png file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXZyq.png) with gray ones.

Based on [official examples](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#replace), I tried the command below and got [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDA6k.png) filled with white not gray.
It becomes white even if other color codes are set for `-fill {COLOR}`.
What's wrong with my command?

```sh
convert -opaque "#00b051" -fill "#808080" -fuzz 20% -strip grid{,_mod}.png
```

Environment:

```sh
❯ brew info imagemagick
==> imagemagick: stable 7.1.0-54 (bottled), HEAD

> sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.6.2
BuildVersion:   21G320

> sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string
Apple M1 Pro

> brew --version
Homebrew 3.6.15-33-g884c4be
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 03ac47958ed; last commit 2022-12-16)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 81aa381950; last commit 2022-12-16)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you try to put options in this order:

1. `-fuzz ...`
2. `-fill ...`
3. `-opaque ...`

Like this:

```bash
convert kL63gnJ.png -fuzz 20% -fill "#808080" -opaque "#01b050" kL63gnJ-new.png
```

This seems really important.

Comment: I didn't realize the order is the key because`man convert` lists options in alphabetical order. Are there any documents explaining order in Imagemagick? Only one I found is this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579299/imagemagick-command-line-option-order-and-categories-of-command-line-parameters

Comment: https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#anatomy

Comment: `-fuzz` and `-fill` are a "settings" options. `-opaque` and `-strip` are "operators" options. In `convert` man page, all options are listed by group and after, they are listed in alphabetical order